# Delete every message in a channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How do I go about deleting every message in a text channel? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228702/deleting-all-messages-in-discord-js-text-channel) worked, but was very slow. (could take up to 15 seconds to delete everything, depending on the amount) I couldn't use that as speed is important in my implementation.

I also tried deleting the entire channel and creating a new one with the same properties, which also worked, but had some problems when the bot thereafter tried to send messages into the channel. (Unknown channel error)

To specify further: this would have to be able to delete up to thousands of messages.

Please ask if you have any questions about my question, and I'll try to edit it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you add code too.

```js
message.channel.messages.fetch().then((messages) => {
    var allMsg = messages.filter((msg) => msg.author.bot);
    message.channel.bulkDelete(allMsg);
});
```

Comment: i am unfortunately not able to add code, as most of what I've done has just been things I've tried and then deleted again. Your solution works great... unless it's over 100 messages. how could I change this so that it could delete every message, even it if was a lot more than 100?